# unidirectional many-to-many relationship with Code First Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I am new to EF, and trying to get many-to-many unidirectional relationship with code first approach. For example, if I have following two classes (not my real model) with  be a N * N relationship between them, but no navigation property from "Customer" side.

```
public class User {
   public int UserId { get; set; }
   public string Email { get; set; }
   public ICollection TaggedCustomers { get; set; }
}
public class Customer {
  public int CustomerId { get; set; }
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping code looks like ...

```
modelBuilder.Entity()
        .HasMany(r => r.TaggedCustomers)
        .WithMany(c => c.ANavgiationPropertyWhichIDontWant)
        .Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                m.MapRightKey("CustomerId");
                m.ToTable("BridgeTableForCustomerAndUser");
        });
```

This syntax force me to have "WithMany" for "Customer" entity.
The following [url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh295843%28v=vs.103%29.aspx), says "By convention, Code First always interprets a unidirectional relationship as one-to-many."

Is it possible to override it, or should I use any other approach?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use this:

```
public class User {
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    // You must use generic collection
    public virtual ICollection<Customer> TaggedCustomers { get; set; }
}

public class Customer {
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And map it with:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(r => r.TaggedCustomers)
    .WithMany() // No navigation property here
    .Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
            m.MapRightKey("CustomerId");
            m.ToTable("BridgeTableForCustomerAndUser");
        });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, what a simple solution. To save my face I will blame it to lack of documentation and not my own ignorance.

Comment: Is it possible to do this with attributes?

Comment: @TDaver: No, attributes can work only if you have navigation properties on both ends and don't expect to control name and columns in junction table.

Comment: .WithMany(). ffs, can you get much more unintuitive? "WithMany... nothing)". At least I finally know how to do it, thanks Ladislav!