# EF Core - .HasMany(r => r.SomeEntity).WithMany() // No navigation property here

Tags: entity-framework-core, many-to-many

can i do this in EntityFrameworkCore?

modelBuilder.Entity()

```
.HasMany(r => r.TaggedCustomers)
.WithMany() // No navigation property here
```

Reference:
[unidirectional many-to-many relationship with Code First Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136026/unidirectional-many-to-many-relationship-with-code-first-entity-framework/64579280#64579280)

Answer (score 0):

I need this ability as well. Upcoming? On the radar?

It's currently the only one of the 18 relationship combinations that can't be done in EFCore. :-(